# A question on pipeline

Tags: data-cleaning, feature-scaling

I made a pipeline with standard scaler and k means .When I fit the pipeline to the training data, Does the standard scaler just fits or fits and transforms the training data?

Answer (score 1):

It fits the scaler and then transforms the training data to pass it to the k-means. The method is called `fit_transform` in scikit-learn.